# Restricting first 2 char of a string

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get the user to input a phone number that must start with 01. Why does the following code not work? I'm guessing it's because the char is not an int? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
int.Parse(phonetextBox.Text);
if ((phonetextBox.Text[0] != 0) || (phonetextBox.Text[1] != 1))
{
MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid phone number! (starts with \'01\');
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Correct phone number!");
}
```

Comment: You're guess about the difference between char and int. You just need to put single quotes around the values to make them chars instead of ints (e.g. `phonetextBox.Text[0] != '0'`)

Comment: first the `int.Parse` will crash when a non number is entered. You would need to use `int.TryParse`. Secondly for such simple check i would rather use `phonetexBox.Text.StartWith("01")`

Comment: Define 'work'. What do you expect and what do you experience instead?

Comment: @Franck - `StartsWith`

Comment: @Franck I have limited the textbox input to only digits, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substring if it always the first 2 characters and has to always be 01

```
string strPhone = phonetextBox.Text;
if (strPhone.Substring(0,2) != "01")
{
MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid phone number! 01";
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Correct phone number!");
}
```

Comment: you mean if (strPhone.Substring(0,2) != "01")

Answer (score 0):

John112358 answer is the best way to check, but for your information, the reason your code did not work is that you wrote

```
if ((phonetextBox.Text[0] != 0) || (phonetextBox.Text[1] != 1))`
```

instead of

```
if ((phonetextBox.Text[0] != '0') || (phonetextBox.Text[1] != '1'))
```

Comment: No, that's not correct either. `phonetextBox.Text[0]` returns a  char, not a string. You'll need to compare it to characters instead of strings.